# ionic3 BrowserAnimationModule

Tags: animation, ionic3

i try to import BrowserAnimaionModule in my project

1- i install npm install web-animations-js @angular/animations@4.0.0 --save

2- i import polyfill   in main.ts

import 'web-animations-js/web-animations.min';

3- and when i try to add BrowserAnimationModule in app.module.ts into imports[]

THIS is js code for the login form

```
 import { Component, trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/core';
  ;
     
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-login',
      templateUrl: 'login-page.html',
     
      animations: [
     
        //For the logo
        trigger('flyInBottomSlow', [
          state('in', style({
            transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
          })),
          transition('void => *', [
            style({transform: 'translate3d(0,2000px,0'}),
            animate('2000ms ease-in-out')
          ])
        ]),
     
        //For the background detail
        trigger('flyInBottomFast', [
          state('in', style({
            transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
          })),
          transition('void => *', [
            style({transform: 'translate3d(0,2000px,0)'}),
            animate('1000ms ease-in-out')
          ])
        ]),
     
        //For the login form
        trigger('bounceInBottom', [
          state('in', style({
            transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)'
          })),
          transition('void => *', [
            animate('2000ms 200ms ease-in', keyframes([
              style({transform: 'translate3d(0,2000px,0)', offset: 0}),
              style({transform: 'translate3d(0,-20px,0)', offset: 0.9}),
              style({transform: 'translate3d(0,0,0)', offset: 1}) 
            ]))
          ])
        ]),
     
            })
        
    }
```

i got this error
Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Comment: Where you use this? `html``and .ts` code?

Comment: i don't underestand your question can you explain more ?

Comment: Can you show the `code` of your implementation?

Comment: ok i will share it now

Answer (score 0):

You are importing trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes  from wrong library.

```
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';  // not @angular/core
```